# PHP Respect Validation Pull Request Fails Travis, Why?

Tags: php, travis-ci, respect-validation

I have updated the grammar in PHP's Respect Validation, but the Travis CI fails each time, even though I have only deleted a few chars using the Github editor, then submitted changes as Pull Request. https://travis-ci.org/Respect/Validation/builds/155072854

Any suggestions as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open one platform build (called also job), for example [PHP 5.6 one](https://travis-ci.org/Respect/Validation/jobs/155072855) and you will find out what are the errors:

```
There were 7 failures:
1) Respect\Validation\Rules\EqualsTest::testShouldThrowTheProperExceptionWhenFailure
Failed asserting that exception message '"24" must equal 42' contains '"24" must be equals 42'.
2) Respect\Validation\Rules\KeyValueTest::testShouldCheckWhenDefinedValuesDoesNotMatch
Failed asserting that exception message 'foo must equal "bar"' contains 'foo must be equals "bar"'.
3) /home/travis/build/Respect/Validation/tests/integration/rules/equals_2.phpt
Failed asserting that format description matches text.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-"test 1234" must be equals "test 123"
+"test 1234" must equal "test 123"
4) /home/travis/build/Respect/Validation/tests/integration/rules/equals_3.phpt
Failed asserting that format description matches text.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-- "test 1234" must be equals "test 123"
+- "test 1234" must equal "test 123"
5) /home/travis/build/Respect/Validation/tests/integration/rules/equals_4.phpt
Failed asserting that format description matches text.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-"test 123" must not be equals "test 123"
+"test 123" must not equal "test 123"
6) /home/travis/build/Respect/Validation/tests/integration/rules/equals_5.phpt
Failed asserting that format description matches text.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-- "test 123" must not be equals "test 123"
+- "test 123" must not equal "test 123"
7) /home/travis/build/Respect/Validation/tests/integration/rules/keyValue_2.phpt
Failed asserting that format description matches text.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-password must be equals "password_confirmation"
+password must equal "password_confirmation"
```

It seems you replace in a default template `equals` with `equal` and this generates failures. There are unit tests that check that behavior is always the same.
If you want to create a PR to an open source project, often you should also update or create tests.

If you want you can locally launch test and check it's all ok. Take a look to the ["Running Tests" section](https://github.com/Respect/Validation/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#running-tests) (on which I contributed) in the official documentation for more information on how to launch tests.

### Install dependencies

```
composer install
```

### Launch tests

#### On Linux

```
vendor/bin/phpunit
```

#### On Windows

```
vendor\bin\phpunit
```